# At What Point is a Persisted Actor Dehydrated/Terminated?

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-persistence

Is there documentation of the lifecycle of a **ReceivePersistentActor**? I'm interested in the circumstances a persistent actor is killed/stopped/dehydrated to allocate resources for other actors. Our application creates a lot of persistent actors and I'm seeing that some are **Terminated**. Is there a timeframe that a persistent actor has to be "inactive" before it is terminated? What other conditions are considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actors are only terminated automatically when:

1. Their parent is shut down or
2. If you're running Akka.Cluster.Sharding, actors that are created via the sharding system will be automatically passivated after two minutes of inactivity: https://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-sharding.html#passivation

Normal persistent actors don't shut down on their own - they'll hang around so long as the `ActorSystem` and their parent actor are live.

Comment: Are they ever terminated to free up resources? The parent is receiving the "Terminated" message, and I figured it's because of resource allocation since we are spinning up thousands of child actors at once.

Comment: No, Akka.NET won't automatically terminate actors outside of those two use cases I mentioned. Programming an actor to terminate after a long idle period using `ReceiveTimeout` is something that many users do frequently though for that very purpose.

Comment: It's worth noting that JVM Akka has added (as of 2.6.18, presumably driven by Akka Serverless) support for pluggable automatic passivation strategies (the other one now shipping with Akka being a fixed limit and then evict the least recently used).  Presumably similar support could eventually be used in Akka.NET.